¿Cómo puedo traer información desde otra tabla diferente al registro que estoy editando en filament?
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de filament en el cual tengo un modelo "Corporativo" que básicamente es una empresa, este modelo está relacionado con una tabla ubicación que guarda el departamento y ciudad en que se encuentra la empresa, junto con su dirección exacta. El hecho es que a la hora de editar un corporativo, la información de la ubicación no se muestra en mi formulario. Esto es lo que he intentado hacer. En el código de mi formulario se puede observar que traigo toda la información del corporativo, la cual a la hora de editar se trae por sí sola al formulario de edición, pero aunque lo he intentado no sucede lo mismo con su ubicación, es decir, los campos Departamento, Ciudad y Dirección detallada quedan en blanco para tener que ser digitados manualment, lo cual no es correcto.
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\Section::make('Información de la empresa')
                    ->schema([
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('nit')
                            ->required()
                            ->unique(Corporativo::class, 'nit', fn ($record) => $record),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('razon_social')
                            ->required(),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('email')
                            ->label('Correo Electrónico')
                            ->email()
                            ->required()
                            ->unique(Corporativo::class, 'email', fn ($record) => $record),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('telefono')
                            ->label('Telefono')
                            ->numeric()
                            ->required()
                            ->unique(Corporativo::class, 'telefono', fn ($record) => $record),
                    ]),
                Forms\Components\Section::make('Información de la ubicación')
                    ->schema([
                        Forms\Components\Select::make('ubicacion.departamento_id')
                            ->label('Departamento')
                            ->options(Departamento::all()->pluck('nombre', 'id'))
                            ->reactive()
                            ->afterStateUpdated(fn (callable $set) => $set('ubicacion.ciudad_id', null))
                            ->required(),
                        Forms\Components\Select::make('ubicacion.ciudad_id')
                            ->label('Ciudad')
                            ->options(function (callable $get) {
                                $departamentoId = $get('ubicacion.departamento_id');
                                if ($departamentoId) {
                                    return Ciudad::where('departamento_id', $departamentoId)->pluck('nombre', 'id');
                                }
                                return [];
                            })
                            ->required(),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('ubicacion.nombre')
                            ->label('Dirección Detallada')
                            ->required(),
                    ])
            ]);
    }

También adjunto el código de mis modelos y cómo están relacionados.
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Corporativo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'nit',
        'razon_social',
        'email',
        'telefono',
        'created_by',
    ];

    public function ubicacion()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Ubicacion::class);
    }

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ubicacion extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'corporativo_id',
        'departamento_id',
        'ciudad_id',
        'nombre',
    ];

    public function corporativo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Corporativo::class);
    }

    public function departamento()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Departamento::class);
    }

    public function ciudad()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ciudad::class);
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Departamento extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['nombre'];

    public function ciudades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ciudad::class);
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ciudad extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'departamento_id'];

    public function departamento()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Departamento::class);
    }
}

